# Unity2D: player boundary increase when maximize on play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a boundary to stop my player to leaving a certain area within my game, I created this boundary by adding a cube to my scene and create a script that adapts the cube to half the size of the camera's width (in update). Within my player's script  I have a function that prevents my player from leaving the cube boundary. It works perfectly, even when I resize the width of my editor, however, when I play the game on 'maximize on play', the width of the boundary is maximized rather than halving the boundary to my preferred size. I worry about this because, I want to put my game on mobile, I'm not sure if maximize on play is actuate to mobile size or playing in normal size editor is more actuate to a normal android phone? Thank you!

Boundary script:

```
public BoxCollider2D cube;
void Start()
{
    cube.size = new Vector2 (240, 0.4f);  //240
}
void Update()
{
    float height = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 1.3f;
    float width = height * Screen.width/ Screen.height; // basically height * screen aspect ratio
    cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(width/10f, width/11f, width/10f);
    Debug.Log (width);
}
```

**NEW UPDATE**

Player's script:

```
public BoxCollider2D cube;
public float moveSpeed = 3f;


void Update () {

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
     var targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     targetPos.z = transform.position.z;
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
 }

void LateUpdate () {
    var left = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector3.zero).x; 
    var right = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint (Vector3.one).x; 
    float x = transform.position.x; 
    if (transform.position.x <= left + cube.bounds.extents.x) { 
        x = left + cube.bounds.extents.x; 
    } else if (transform.position.x >= right - cube.bounds.extents.x) {
        x = right - cube.bounds.extents.x; 
    }
    transform.position = new Vector3 (x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: How are you moving your character? You can edit that part of the code into your answer

Comment: sure! I have updated my code!

Comment: @Programmer do you have any ideas?

Comment: Note. I don't understand what you are doing,I have to before I attempt to put an answer. Let me guess, you are moving an object but don't want that object to move out of the screen boundaries? It would be better to show what you are doing even with screenshot. I am lost.